# Use require & es6 import side by side

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, commonjs, es6-module-loader

*Is there any pitfalls of using webpack's require and es6's imports in the same file?*

Example (two imports are in the same file):

```
import View1 from 'mobileComponents/View1';

//because if statement is impossible in es6 imports which are static
const View2 = require(process.env.PROJECT === 'mobile' ? 'mobileComponents/View2' : 'desktopComponents/View2');
```

I'm using es6 imports. I just started a desktop version of a project and want to reuse much of code. Sometimes I want to import desktop version of a code and don't want totally downgrade to webpack requires.

Comment: I don't see any. `import`s are translated to `require`s anyway.

Comment: @FelixKling but what's the benefit of being static? If imports are translated to require than they should be dynamic as require is

Comment: Well, they are only currently converted to `require` because no environment supports ES6 modules yet. *"but what's the benefit of being static?"* That makes dependency analysis easier. Webpack wouldn't be able to handler `process.env.PROJECT === 'mobile' ? 'mobileComponents/View2' : 'desktopComponents/View2'` either if you didn't enable plugins that replace `process.env.PROJECT` and perform constant folding.

Comment: @FelixKling got it, thanks!!